# D3 Tree with Collapsing Boxes using D3 Version 4

Tags: d3.js, tree

We were able to use this example here(https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) and achieve the Collapsible tree diagram. We are looking to have boxes in here instead of circles with text aligned inside it. 
Below is the diagram which we are trying to achieve using Version4. 
Please let know what change needs to be done in the above code using d3 version 4 to achieve this
[image: Collapisible Tree with Boxes]

Comment: you will have to replace all the circle elements with svg-rect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have made necessary code changes to accommodate your requirement.

Hope it helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .node rect {
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        fill: #fff;
    }
    
    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var treeData =
  {
    "name": "NODE NAME 1",  
    "subname": "CODE N1",    
    "fill":"orange",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "subname": "CODE N1",    
        "fill":"blue"
      },
      { "name": "NODE NAME 2.2","subname": "CODE N1"  ,"fill":"blue" },
      { "name": "NODE NAME 2.3","subname": "CODE N1","fill":"blue",
      "children": [
          { "name": "NODE NAME 3.3","fill":"blue","subname": "CODE N1",
           "children": [{
               "name":"NODE NAME 4.1","subname": "CODE N1",
               "fill":"#d281d2"
           }
               ] },
          { "name": "NODE NAME 3.4","fill":"blue", "subname": "CODE N1" ,
           "children": [{
               "name":"NODE NAME 4.2", "subname": "CODE N1" ,
               "fill":"#d281d2"
           }
               ]
           }
        ]
        }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

    var rectHeight = 60, rectWidth = 120;
    
    nodeEnter.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("width", rectWidth)
      .attr("height", rectHeight)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", (rectHeight/2)*-1)
      .attr("rx","5")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d.data.fill;
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", "-.35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("dy", "1.75em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return 13;
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.subname; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You Roopashree. This solution above worked for me.

Comment: Hi, Can we add a label to the link, such that on mouse hover on a link it displays a text? similar to here https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460 using d3 v5.

Comment: Just what I needed! How should I change from horizontal to vertical tree?

Comment: can we upgrade this to version 7, I am did try, everything is working except the on click expand part

   `https://vizhub.com/junaidaj86/206ee6d50e304342bf88387ba640721e`